# Is there a way to monitor optimizer's step in Pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, optimizer-hints

Consider that you are using a Pytorch optimizer such as torch.optim.Adam(model_parameters).

So in your training loop you will have something like:

```
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model_parameters)
# put the training loop here

loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
optimizer.zero()
```

Is there a way to monitor what steps are taking your optimizer ? To make sure that you are not on a flat area and thus taking no steps since the gradient are null. Maybe checking the learning rate would be a solution ?

Comment: You can just make sure your model hasn't converged by monitoring that your loss is decreasing every few iterations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering to myself here.

The best practice would be (in PyTorch) to check the gradient of the leaf tensors.
If the gradient is None but is_leaf attribute is set to True, something is obviously buggy.

torch.nn.Parameters('insert your tensor here') is especially confusing to this regard.
As the Tensor needs to be defined as a torch.nn.Parameters to be succesfully updated.
I would advise not to use tensor.requires_grad_(True) as is confuses torch. Only set your parameters as above.